# Prisma query issues in Next.js

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

Im tying to create a query file called page/api/db.tsx.  I know my Prisma connection works but i cannot get my query to work correctly.  the actual query Im trying to do is this:

```
SELECT linearadmins.linearId
FROM linearadmins
JOIN "User" ON linearadmins.id = "User".id
```

I get errors saying the Users arg is wrong or that I cant use select and include together. I keep trying variations and keep getting errors.

here is the latest error:

```
  Server Error
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.linearadmins.findMany()` invocation:

{
  select: {
  ~~~~~~
    linearid: true,
    name: true
  },
  where: {
    User: {
    ~~~~
      id: {
        not: null
      }
    }
  },
  include: {
  ~~~~~~~
    User: {
      select: {
        id: true
      }
    }
  }
}

Unknown arg `User` in where.User for type linearadminsWhereInput. Did you mean `AND`? Available args:
type linearadminsWhereInput {
  AND?: linearadminsWhereInput | List<linearadminsWhereInput>
  OR?: List<linearadminsWhereInput>
  NOT?: linearadminsWhereInput | List<linearadminsWhereInput>
  id?: StringFilter | String
  name?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null
  email?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null
  linearid?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null
  status?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null
}
Please either use `include` or `select`, but not both at the same time.
```

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { PrismaClient, linearadmins } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const users = await prisma.linearadmins.findMany({
    select: {
      linearid: true
    },
    where: {
      User: {
        id: {
          not: null
        }
      }
    },
    include: {
      User: {
        select: {
          id: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  res.status(200).json(users);
}
```

this is what Im trying to use now.  I have a User table and a linearadmins table. they both use the field 'id' to connect. I want to return the field 'linearid'. the query works inside of Supabases sql editor but i cant get the query to work in Prisma.

Comment: I've tried findUnique as well, neither work.